# Find differences between two spreadsheets

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I have this code that is supposed to compare two Excel sheets. The code is working fine for small comparisons. I did a test run with 7 rows and 2 columns.

The code itself works as follows: it compares the two sheets and copies the differences into a new workbook.

However, the code should be applied to files that have around 16 columns and a lot of rows (around 206700).  It doesn't seem to scale very well to these larger sheets - the process is shown “Not Responding”, for more than ten minutes when I gave up.

This is how my excel file columns looks likem, keeping in mind that most of them contain text and only few times numbers are used.
[image]

I'd like to improve the performance with these larger files; any other suggestions for improvement are also welcome.

```
Sub Compare2WorkSheets(ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet)

  Dim ws1row As Long, ws2row As Long, ws1col As Integer, ws2col As Integer
  Dim maxrow As Long, maxcol As Integer, colval1 As String, colval2 As String
  Dim report As Workbook, difference As Long
  Dim row As Long, col As Integer

  Set report = Workbooks.Add

  With ws1.UsedRange
    ws1row = .Rows.Count
    ws1col = .Columns.Count
  End With

  With ws2.UsedRange
    ws2row = .Rows.Count
    ws2col = .Columns.Count
  End With

  maxrow = ws1row
  maxcol = ws1col
  If maxrow < ws2row Then maxrow = ws2row
  If maxcol < ws2col Then maxcol = ws2col

  difference = 0

  For col = 1 To maxcol
    For row = 1 To maxrow
      colval1 = ""
      colval2 = ""
      colval1 = ws1.Cells(row, col).Formula
      colval2 = ws2.Cells(row, col).Formula
      If colval1 <> colval2 Then
        difference = difference + 1
        Cells(row, col).Formula = colval1 & "<> " & colval2
        Cells(row, col).Interior.Color = 255
        Cells(row, col).Font.ColorIndex = 2
        Cells(row, col).Font.Bold = True
      End If
    Next row
  Next col

  Columns("A:B").ColumnWidth = 25
  report.Saved = True

  If difference = 0 Then
    report.Close False
  End If
  Set report = Nothing
  MsgBox difference & " cells contain different data! ", vbInformation, _
         "Comparing Two       Worksheets"
End Sub
```

Comment: "16 columns and a lot of rows (around 206700)" Have you tried scaling up more slowly? What happens with 3 columns and 400 rows? 6 columns and 800 rows? Now all you can tell us you don't have the patience to see whether it still works after 10 minutes, which doesn't tell us much about the current inefficiency.

Comment: Can you tell us more about how this code is used (executed in 1 of the spreadsheets, or in a 3rd), what kind of data (length) we're talking about and how the cells are formatted (are they text, numbers, currency, date)? This could all be relevant.

Comment: @Mast  I actually have waited almost 1 hour and the file was stil saying "Not responding" .  I just tried it with 10k rows and all the columns . It took more than a 1min. If you look at the question I also have added a picture oh how my excel file approx looks like

Comment: It looks like you're comparing the formulas in each of the cells and not the values of the cells. Is this correct?

Comment: @Close-Voters: Please read the [tag:vba] tag wiki. Excel "freezing" and/or "(not responding)" **is not broken code**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May try the modified code using Arrays to Compare. Tested with 250000  rows X 26 columns of random data and every 5th cells have value difference (Total 130000 differences). It takes around 18 secs to compare and another 22 secs to completes report generation with total 40 seconds only.

```
Sub Compare2WorkSheets(ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet)
  Dim ws1row As Long, ws2row As Long, ws1col As Integer, ws2col As Integer
  Dim maxrow As Long, maxcol As Integer, colval1 As String, colval2 As String
  Dim Report As Workbook, difference As Long
  Dim row As Long, col As Integer
  Dim Arr1 As Variant, Arr2 As Variant, Arr3 As Variant, Rng As Range
  Dim tm As Double
  tm = Timer

  'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  'Application.EnableEvents = False


  With ws1.UsedRange
    ws1row = .Rows.Count
    ws1col = .Columns.Count
  End With

  With ws2.UsedRange
    ws2row = .Rows.Count
    ws2col = .Columns.Count
  End With

  maxrow = ws1row
  maxcol = ws1col
  If maxrow < ws2row Then maxrow = ws2row
  If maxcol < ws2col Then maxcol = ws2col

  Debug.Print maxrow, maxcol
  Arr1 = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, 1), ws1.Cells(maxrow, maxcol)).Formula
  Arr2 = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(1, 1), ws2.Cells(maxrow, maxcol)).Formula
  ReDim Arr3(1 To UBound(Arr1, 1), 1 To UBound(Arr1, 2))

  difference = 0

  For col = 1 To maxcol
    For row = 1 To maxrow
      If Arr1(row, col) <> Arr2(row, col) Then
      difference = difference + 1
      Arr3(row, col) = Arr1(row, col) & "<> " & Arr2(row, col)
      Else
      Arr3(row, col) = ""
      End If
    Next row
  Next col

  Debug.Print " Calc secs " & Timer - tm
  If difference > 0 Then
  Set Report = Workbooks.Add

  With Report.ActiveSheet
  .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(Arr3, 1), UBound(Arr3, 2)).Value = Arr3
  .Columns("A:B").ColumnWidth = 25
  Set Rng = .Range(Report.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), Report.ActiveSheet.Cells(UBound(Arr3, 1), UBound(Arr3, 2)))
  End With

  With Rng
  .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:="=""""" '""""""""
  .FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
   With .FormatConditions(1)
        .Interior.Color = 255
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.ColorIndex = 2
    End With
   End With

  Debug.Print "Report Generated secs " & Timer - tm
  End If
 'Set Report = Nothing
  'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  'Application.EnableEvents = True

  MsgBox difference & " cells contain different data! ", vbInformation, "Comparing Two       Worksheets"
End Sub
```

Since I personally don't prefer to keep calculations, event processing and screen updating off (in normal cases) i haven't used that standard lines. However you may use these standard techniques, depending on the working file condition.

Comment: thank a lot , works so smooth. I have some small features I want to add. I might need some help with that. Should I ask here or just edit my question and add those parts there ?

Comment: in case the row is identical, I want it to be copied on the report sheet (without any change of color of font).  I tried iimplementing it on the code however, even the rows that are the same are canging color and getting the background color

Comment: It is not clear, do you want to copy & list values of only identical rows in the report sheet and difference is not to be calculated?

Comment: @ Ahmed AU Is it ok if I post another question about that because since reviewing the files some  I have to add something and the logic behind it is unclear and I'm not managing to find a way. I would link you to the question

Comment: if it is not about efficiency and performance may post it it on SO. If this question solves your efficiency problem may pl accept the answer.

Comment: please have a look at my new question. It is in regard to your code from here   [https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/226346/compare-two-excel-sheets-by-cell-content]

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues with your code:

1) Try to avoid unqualified references, this means always specify the worksheet, when referencing a cell.

2) Try to avoid formatting a lot of single cells, rather format them all at once at the end. Formatting slows down Excel a lot!

3) When handeling a great deal of Ranges, `Integer` can be insufficient, use `Long` instead.

````vb
Sub Compare2WorkSheets(ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet)

  Dim ws1row As Long, ws2row As Long, ws1col As Long, ws2col As Long
  Dim maxrow As Long, maxcol As Integer, colval1 As String, colval2 As String
  Dim report As Workbook, difference As Long
  Dim row As Long, col As Long
  Dim unionRng as Range

  Set report = Workbooks.Add

  With ws1.UsedRange
    ws1row = .Rows.Count
    ws1col = .Columns.Count
  End With

  With ws2.UsedRange
    ws2row = .Rows.Count
    ws2col = .Columns.Count
  End With

  maxrow = ws1row
  maxcol = ws1col
  If maxrow < ws2row Then maxrow = ws2row
  If maxcol < ws2col Then maxcol = ws2col

  difference = 0

  With report.Sheets(1)
    For col = 1 To maxcol
      For row = 1 To maxrow
        colval1 = ""
        colval2 = ""
        colval1 = ws1.Cells(row, col).Formula
        colval2 = ws2.Cells(row, col).Formula

        If colval1 <> colval2 Then
          difference = difference + 1
          .Cells(row, col).Value = colval1 & "<> " & colval2 'I guess you want to show, that the formulas used are not equal.
          If unionRng is Nothing Then
            Set unionRng = .Cells(row, col)
          Else
            Set unionRng = Application.Union(unionRng, .Cells(row, col))
          End If
        End If
      Next row
    Next col

    .Columns("A:B").ColumnWidth = 25
  End With

  unionRng.Interior.Color = 255
  unionRng.Font.ColorIndex = 2
  unionRng.Font.Bold = True
  report.SaveAs Filename:="report.xlsx"

  If difference = 0 Then
    report.Close False
  End If
  Set report = Nothing
  MsgBox difference & " cells contain different data! ", vbInformation, _
         "Comparing Two       Worksheets"
End Sub
```
````

Comment: I'm getting error   *Invalid procedure call or invalid argument*  at  __Set unionRng = Application.Union(unionRng, .Cells(row, col))__

Comment: See the edit, forgot to check for the case, that `unionRng` is set for the first time.

Comment: It's been 40 mins since the code is running, as it for no it's showing __Not Responding__ but I guess files are still being compared.  The problem is, this is taking way to long and an end point doesn't look near.

Comment: I have serious apprehensions using union range method with large non contiguous area count at least in excel 2007. May refer my [post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/224874/brute-force-looping-formatting-or-create-union-range-format-which-is-effici/224937#224937)  and may provide some more information..

Answer (score 2):

My answer is very similar to Ahmed AU with a few exceptions.
- I didn't bother adding the Conditional formatting because everything on the new worksheet represents changes. 
- The other main difference is that I match the Ranges using the Range addresses.  These will automatically adjust for differences in column and rows count and starting cell.

### Refactored Code

```
Sub Compare2WorkSheets(ByRef Worksheet1 As Worksheet, ByRef Worksheet2 As Worksheet)
    Dim t As Double: t = Timer
    Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range

    SetRanges Worksheet1, Worksheet2, Range1, Range2

    Dim Values1, Values2, Results
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, Count As Long
    Values1 = Range1.Value
    Values2 = Range2.Value
    ReDim Results(1 To UBound(Values1), 1 To UBound(Values1, 2))
    For r = 1 To UBound(Values1)
        For c = 1 To UBound(Values1, 2)
            If Values1(r, c) <> Values2(r, c) Then
                Count = Count + 1
                Results(r, c) = Values1(r, c) & vbNewLine & Values2(r, c)
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Workbooks.Add.Worksheets(1).Range(Range1.Address).Value = Results
    Debug.Print "Compare2WorkSheets: ", Worksheet1.Name; " to "; Worksheet2.Name
    Debug.Print "Runtime in Second(s):"; Round(Timer - t, 2)
    Debug.Print "Number of Cells per Worksheet: "; Range1.CountLarge
    Debug.Print "Number of Differences: "; Count
    MsgBox "There were " & Count & " Differences"
End Sub

Sub SetRanges(ByRef Worksheet1 As Worksheet, ByRef Worksheet2 As Worksheet, ByRef Range1 As Range, ByRef Range2 As Range)
    With Worksheet1
        Set Range1 = Union(.UsedRange, .Range(Worksheet2.UsedRange.Address))
    End With
    With Worksheet2
        Set Range2 = Union(.UsedRange, .Range(Worksheet1.UsedRange.Address))
    End With
End Sub
```

### Results

[image: Immediate Window Screenshot]

Comment: Again you win my respect, the way you matched the Ranges using the Range addresses. would you please throw some light on my recent serious apprehensions about using union range method with large non contiguous area count at least in excel 2007. May refer my to [boring post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/224874/brute-force-looping-formatting-or-create-union-range-format-which-is-effici/224937#224937)] and may provide some more information. Actually while posting that I hoped for some info from you, @Tim William etc

Comment: @TinMan please have a look at my new post, it is regarding the code from question.  [https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/226346/compare-two-excel-sheets-by-cell-content]

Answer (score 1):

My answer makes the assumption that you mean to compare the **values** of the data and not the **formulas**, though much of the other comments here remain valid for your code.

1. [Identify your function parameters as `ByRef` or `ByVal`](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/byref-byval.html). As you may guess, passing a variable "by reference" generally allows you to reference the variable as held by the caller and make modifications to its value (there are some exceptions, but this is the concept). Passing a variable "by value" effectively copies the value of the variable to a new variable in your routine. When passing objects, such as `Worksheet`, to a function, I nearly always pass these objects `ByRef` so I'm thinking there is some deep copy action happening.
2. It's generally recommended to declare your variables as close to its first use as possible. This will save you (and anyone else reviewing your code) from having to scroll up/down to determine variable types and definitions.

So to declare references to the two source worksheets would look like this:

```
Dim area1 As Range
Dim area2 As Range
Set area1 = ws1.UsedRange
Set area2 = ws2.UsedRange
```

3. You can simplify how you determine the maximum number of rows and columns using two statements with the `IIf`.

Notice how I'm overwriting the initial `Set` of each area variable, possibly expanding it to cover the largest possible range.

```
'--- calculate the max-sized range for the data and expand
'    the ranges as needed
Dim maxRows As Long
Dim maxCols As Long
maxRows = IIf(area1.Rows.Count > area2.Rows.Count, _
              area1.Rows.Count, area2.Rows.Count)
maxCols = IIf(area1.Columns.Count > area2.Columns.Count, _
              area1.Columns.Count, area2.Columns.Count)
Set area1 = area1.Resize(maxRows, maxCols)
Set area2 = area2.Resize(maxRows, maxCols)
```

4. Here's where the real speed improvement kicks in - [memory-based arrays (see #19 and #20)](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/). When you're working with a `Range` object, Excel incurs a lot of overhead to manage all the aspects of that range object. This is expensive in execution time, especially if all you want is the value of each cell in the range. It's a quick step to copy all the values into an array.

Note that each array is declared as a `Variant` without array dimensions. The assignment of the range `.Value` will cast the variant into an array:

```
'--- create memory-based arrays for the data in the ranges
Dim data1 As Variant
Dim data2 As Variant
data1 = area1.value
data2 = area2.value
```

5. In keeping with the idea of speed, I'm creating a `Collection` of items that captures all of the differences/discrepancies discovered between the two worksheet areas. Because the `Collection` is also a memory-based object, it will also be very fast.

Each entry in the `Collection` is a comma separated value string, which we'll pull apart later on.

```
'--- we'll build up the report as a series of discrepancy
'    entries in a Collection for now
Dim report As Collection
Set report = New Collection

Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long
For r = 1 To maxRows
    For c = 1 To maxCols
        If data1(r, c) <> data2(r, c) Then
            '--- add a discrepancy entry to log the difference
            '    as a comma separated string:
            '          "row,column,value1 <> value2"
            report.Add r & "," & c & "," & data1(r, c) & " <> " & data2(r, c)
        End If
    Next c
Next r
```

6. The example here shows two different ways to present your results, depending on your requirements. The first simply reports the results as a virtual list (array) that is copied directly to a worksheet. (I didn't create a separate workbook, for simplicity of my example.)

This list does not mimic the dimensions of the data areas at all.

```
'--- results as a simple list
Dim reportData As Variant
ReDim reportData(1 To report.Count + 1, 1 To 3)
reportData(1, 1) = "Row"
reportData(1, 2) = "Column"
reportData(1, 3) = "Difference"
For r = 2 To report.Count + 1
    Dim parts() As String
    parts = Split(report.Item(r - 1), ",")
    reportData(r, 1) = parts(0)
    reportData(r, 2) = parts(1)
    reportData(r, 3) = parts(2)
Next r
Set finalReport = reportWS.Range("A1").Resize(report.Count + 1, 3)
finalReport.value = reportData
```

An alternative solution is to report the discrepancies in a worksheet range that is dimensionally similar to your source worksheets. Your original post is trying to applying shading to cells with differences.

The example here works very fast for two reasons:  1) because of how we've collected the discrepancies earlier, there's no need to loop over every single cell in the range. We have the row and column of each discrepancy, so we can directly (and quickly) just set the highlight colors and be finished, and 2) by disabling/enabling `Application.ScreenUpdating` we prevent Excel from interacting with the display, and that gains more speed.

```
'--- results as a data range with highlighted cells
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set reportWS = Sheet4
Set finalReport = reportWS.Range("A1").Resize(maxRows, maxCols)
Dim discrepancy As Variant
For Each discrepancy In report
    'Dim parts() As String
    parts = Split(discrepancy, ",")
    With finalReport.Cells(CLng(parts(0)), CLng(parts(1)))
        .value = parts(2)
        .Interior.Color = 255
        .Font.ColorIndex = 2
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
Next discrepancy
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Here is the full module you can use for testing:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    CompareData Sheet1, Sheet2
End Sub

Sub CompareData(ByRef ws1 As Worksheet, ByRef ws2 As Worksheet)
    Dim area1 As Range
    Dim area2 As Range
    Set area1 = ws1.UsedRange
    Set area2 = ws2.UsedRange

    '--- calculate the max-sized range for the data and expand
    '    the ranges as needed
    Dim maxRows As Long
    Dim maxCols As Long
    maxRows = IIf(area1.Rows.Count > area2.Rows.Count, _
                  area1.Rows.Count, area2.Rows.Count)
    maxCols = IIf(area1.Columns.Count > area2.Columns.Count, _
                  area1.Columns.Count, area2.Columns.Count)
    Set area1 = area1.Resize(maxRows, maxCols)
    Set area2 = area2.Resize(maxRows, maxCols)

    '--- create memory-based arrays for the data in the ranges
    Dim data1 As Variant
    Dim data2 As Variant
    data1 = area1.value
    data2 = area2.value

    '--- we'll build up the report as a series of discrepancy
    '    entries in a Collection for now
    Dim report As Collection
    Set report = New Collection

    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    For r = 1 To maxRows
        For c = 1 To maxCols
            If data1(r, c) <> data2(r, c) Then
                '--- add a discrepancy entry to log the difference
                '    as a comma separated string:
                '          "row,column,value1 <> value2"
                report.Add r & "," & c & "," & data1(r, c) & " <> " & data2(r, c)
            End If
        Next c
    Next r

    Dim reportWB As Workbook
    Dim reportWS As Worksheet
    Dim finalReport As Range
    'Set reportWB = Workbooks.Add
    'Set reportWS = reportWB.Sheets(1)
    Set reportWS = Sheet3

    '--- results as a simple list
    Dim reportData As Variant
    ReDim reportData(1 To report.Count + 1, 1 To 3)
    reportData(1, 1) = "Row"
    reportData(1, 2) = "Column"
    reportData(1, 3) = "Difference"
    For r = 2 To report.Count + 1
        Dim parts() As String
        parts = Split(report.Item(r - 1), ",")
        reportData(r, 1) = parts(0)
        reportData(r, 2) = parts(1)
        reportData(r, 3) = parts(2)
    Next r
    Set finalReport = reportWS.Range("A1").Resize(report.Count + 1, 3)
    finalReport.value = reportData

    '--- results as a data range with highlighted cells
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set reportWS = Sheet4
    Set finalReport = reportWS.Range("A1").Resize(maxRows, maxCols)
    Dim discrepancy As Variant
    For Each discrepancy In report
        'Dim parts() As String
        parts = Split(discrepancy, ",")
        With finalReport.Cells(CLng(parts(0)), CLng(parts(1)))
            .value = parts(2)
            .Interior.Color = 255
            .Font.ColorIndex = 2
            .Font.Bold = True
        End With
    Next discrepancy
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you a lot for your detailed answer. I needed to add some new features to the code and unfortunately that is above my vba knowledge. can you please have a look at my new post ?   [https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/226346/compare-two-excel-sheets-by-cell-content]